# Angular - remove empty option(?) from select element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select element that is being used for a list and is bound to an array. When the array is empty, an option element is being added to the select element - as shown below. This is causing the list to be highlighted, which I don't want

```
<select id="activeItemsSelect" ng-model="activeItems" ng-options="item.assessment_title for item in activeAssessments" size="5" class="span10" empty-select>
```

I am trying to remove the option element and have attempted to do so in a directive, empty-select, albeit unsuccessfully. How can I remove this option element?

Thanks, in advance for any and all replies.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is simply disabled the select. Angular always adds an empty option if the ng-model doesn't exist as an option.

```
<select id="activeItemsSelect" 
        class="span10"
        size="5" 
        ng-model="activeItems" 
        ng-disabled="activeItems.length == 0"
        ng-options="item.assessment_title for item in activeAssessments"
        ></select>
```

**Edit**: As of more recent Angular Versions per the docs:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions: Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option. See example below for demonstration.

```
<select id="activeItemsSelect" 
        class="span10"
        size="5" 
        ng-model="activeItems" 
        ng-disabled="activeItems.length == 0"
        ng-options="item.assessment_title for item in activeAssessments">
  <option value="">Select an Option</option>
</select>
```

You may even want to rebind the option to some text when the array is empty.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to directly remove the empty option element?

Comment: This sentence solved my problem of removing the first empty element: "Angular always adds an empty option if the ***ng-model*** doesn't exist as an option." So, please verify that the variable "activeItems" does exist on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add an empty option manually (angular should catch that), and use `ng-switch` for removing it

Comment: Well I did originally try with an empty option (although it's not listed above) and it got replaced with the Angular (?) option. How would I use ng-switch to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the model used with the select, so the select widget will have default value when shown, instead of showing empty. In your case do something like the following in your controller.

```
$scope.activeItems = $scope.activeAssessments[0].assessment_title
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this directive which supports expressions for the `ng-size` attribute:

```
.directive('ngSize', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (element.prop("tagName") !== 'SELECT') {
                throw new Error('ngSize can only be applied to <select>-elements');
            }

            var exp = attrs.ngSize;
            scope.$watch(exp, function (newVal) {
                attrs.$set('size', newVal);
            });
        }
    }
})
```